# Python NLP Topic Modelling Assign topics to each row

Tags: python, nlp

How to assign topic to each text after finding topics from bertopic topic modelling?

Comment: Can you be more specific ? What is the goal, what form do you expect ? What do you mean by *assign* ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.